# Ignore WhiteSpaces with NSPredicates and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple application which contains a `UITableViewController` which is populated by the user adding in some information into a set of `UITextFields` in another view. That date gets saved to `Core Data` and the `UITableView` gets populated using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

I have come across a strange set of situations where users for some reason put a space before an entry. So if the entry is "Wedding", some users (accidentally) put a space before Wedding, so it becomes  Wedding with the space at the start.

Because of this, my `UITableView` treats that as a separate entry to just "Wedding" and so because my `UITableView` is set to be alphabetical according to the event, Wedding with a space at the start appears before Anniversary, whereas Wedding without a space at the start appears after Anniversary.

With this in mind, I want to be able to ignore whitespaces, so that a user can enter Wedding with or Without a space at the front, and it:

1) Always ignores the space and maintains the alphabetical nature of the UITableView
2) Treats Wedding as the same entry (with and without a space).

My `NSPredicate` looks like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Occasion" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;
NSPredicate *o = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categories.occasion.@count !=0"];
if ([self.eventSearchBar.text length] > 0) {
    NSPredicate *eventPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[c] %@", self.eventSearchBar.text];
    NSPredicate *compPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[o, eventPredicate]];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:compPredicate];
}
else
{
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:o];

}
```

Any guidance on ignoring the white space here would be really efficient. I've tried changing the word CONTAINS to MATCHES but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Try trimming white spaces before saving to core data. ie `stringToSave = [stringToSave stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];]` and save.

Comment: Thanks @Akhilrajtr - that's a very interesting approach, but will that mess up white spaces in the middle of names? For example, if someone puts "John's Wedding", would that white space get ignored as well? I basically only want the white space ignored at the start. The middle and end is perfectly fine..

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only remove characters from both ends. So the space between words will not removed. ie. The space "John's Wedding" will not removed and @"  Wedding    " will change to @"Wedding" by trimming from both ends.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I tried the code and it still added the space and treated it as a different entry

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have tried as an edit?